# g++ -- Undefined Reference to main in 86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o:

Tags: compiling, c++, g++

I am trying to compile a simple C++ Hello World program to test my environment, however, whenever I try, I get this Error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is my compiler option:
`g++ main.cpp -o main`

Comment: So, does your `main.cpp` file actually contain a top-level `main()` function?

Comment: Post your main.cpp and we can maybe help a little more...

Answer (score 0):

This is my alt account. my code was:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void){
std::cout << "Hello World!\n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provide, you never close the double quote.
It shouldn't cause this issue though
[missing_quote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wb6X.png)
If this doesn't solve your issue, you may try to reinstall your build tools.

Comment: Yeah that was just a typo. I tried reinstalling my build tools (g++) and that didn't work. Any other suggestions?